# How to see Page Size in Xcode latest code signature format

Tags: xcode, codesign, der

**I got this message from Apple**

> An app signed with a codesign version provided on an older macOS, like
> Catalina (10.15) will not run on iOS 15 because the latest version you
> can install is Xcode 12.4. Xcode 12.5 seems to change the behavior of
> codesigning. When installing you get the error message The code
> signature version is no longer supported. Is there a workaround?

They also suggested following [Using the Latest Code Signature Format](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/using-the-latest-code-signature-format) documentation for making the app compatible with the new signature format.

One of the steps was to see Page Size by running this command.

```
% codesign -dv /path/to/MyApp.app
```

They said that the output will have Page size.

```
Page size=4096
 -7=f4c7c0ae394247097dca9b19333001200747691e1d9e25ec0cf0f35a8ade21f3
 -6=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 -5=7379374fd375633558fd972e33809c06e61f9f8191f67c71875899b0dc290945
 -4=0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
 -3=53cc3cc9830555e6d7bc864522fdf160b61ccc0d2fda9331368d333dfaa4fe24
```

But when I run the command I don't see the Page Size. Here is the output.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To see the page size in xcode you need to use this:

```
codesign -dvvvvv MyApp.app
```

If it's not working try to Re-sign your app and try again this command.

Comment: You are awesome! It works like a charm. Can you tell more about the -dvvvvv part in the command? Where did you find it and what does it mean?